# Performance comparison between Jasper server and Penatho BI server for the reports

Tags: jasper-reports, pentaho, jasperserver

I wanted know the performance comparison between the Jasper server and Pentaho server.
for instance, when i run the report in the these server, which is more faster.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them use same Jasper Report libraries for generating reports. So, there is no difference.